# Passing Argument in C#

Tags: c#

How can I input "English" as a default language, if the user doesn't input their preferred language? Without using if/else statement.

Here is my simple code:

```
using System;

namespace Practice1._3
{
    class Program
    {            
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What's your name:");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Age:");
            string Age = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Preferred language:");
            string language = Console.ReadLine();


            Console.WriteLine("\n-----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Your name is " + name);           
            Console.WriteLine("Your age is " + Age);
            Console.WriteLine("Your language is " + language);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why avoid if/else?

Comment: "doesn't input their preferred language" - do you mean if the user just hits Enter when asked for the language?

Comment: And how does this relate to your question's title?

Comment: I suggest using current culture, e.g. `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.EnglishName` as a default language

Comment: The word "if" is in your question, you'll have conditional behaviour depending on user input.
Eventually, you will use an if/else statement; ternary operator or null-coalescing operator are shorter if/else statements.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a ternary conditional operator.

```
Console.WriteLine("Your language is : {0}", language == "" ? "English" : language);
```

Comment: Or `Console.WriteLine($"Your language is : {(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(language) ? "English" : language)}");`

Comment: Which is a (shorter) way to use an if/else statement :)

Answer (score 0):

Because of this line `string language = Console.ReadLine();`, it cannot be possible to do it without checking what is already stored in the variable. I was thinking of a default value. Even if you set a default value, this line will override it with an empty string. [Check here for more about string vs null](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/bean-validation002.htm#:%7E:text=An%20empty%20string%20is%20a,string%20is%20represented%20by%20null%20.)

Like A. Petit suggests above, I also suggest an if statement to check the input and display your language accordingly. You can use ternary for this. a ternary Is also a form of the if statement.

```
Console.WriteLine("What's your name:");
string name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Age:");
string Age = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Preferred language:");
string language = Console.ReadLine();

//check if language is entered. If not, use a default langage, else, use the entered language
language = language=="" || language == null? "English": language;

Console.WriteLine("\n-----------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("Your name is " + name);
Console.WriteLine("Your age is " + Age);
Console.WriteLine("Your language is " + language);
```